# Is it possible to make the header be fixed on the left and not at the top in Crystal Report using vb.net

Tags: crystal-reports

how we could fixed the header on the right not on the top
like this [image]

Comment: follow some steps step 1 go to section expert step 2 place your text to the most right side as you wish then expand your section according to height that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the Section Expert and select your header section you can enable the "Underlay Following Sections" property for the header section.  This will allow the sections that follow to effectively print on top of the header section.  At this point its a matter of designing the content of you header so that it does not extend beyond the point where you wish to end the left side section.  Then when designing the content for the remaining sections be certain that nothing is placed on the left side of the sections where the header will be displayed.

Using this method will give the appearance you want in your output, but in truth, the header section and all other sections are still the full width of the page, its just up to you to control placement of your data fields and objects to ensure header section doesn't overlap with the other sections in ways that create undesired outputs.